# How do I run a .JAR file via the terminal

Tags: command-line, java, eclipse

Mispelled classname in manifest.txt file caused this error

[image][image]Im trying to run a java file outside of my IDE by exporting the .jar file to my documents folder and trying to display the text 'hello world'in the file on the terminal line. I attempted to create a Manifest.txt file with this in it,

Main-Class: lightning.java.hello.MyFirstClass

I then used this script to create a file MyJar.jar and got this back,

lightning@rigel5:~$ jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt lightning.java.hello/*.class
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Manifest.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:171)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)

Comment: I couldn’t get your question. Do you mean a command to open a jar file? It’s `java -jar path-to-file`.

Comment: yeah Im trying to export a .jar file to the terminal line

Comment: lightning@rigel5:~$ java /home/lighting/Documents/temp.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class .home.lighting.Documents.temp.jar
lightning@rigel5:~$

Comment: I exported the jar file to the documents folder and I am hoping to run it on the terminal line... its a 'hello world'

Comment: at least I thought I did. how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run java package using this command on your terminal:

```
java -jar MyFirstClass.jar
```

If you don't have Java Runtime Edition (JRE) you'll need to install `default-jre` package.

Comment: lightning@rigel5:~$ java -jar MyFirstClass.jar 
Error: Unable to access jarfile MyFirstClass.jar
lightning@rigel5:~$

Comment: it seems you are on the wrong path, because it can not find the jar file. make sure you are in the jar file directory when using the command.

Comment: Yep I sure do... Would love to solve this  ...So how would I type that in the terminal?

Comment: I had mispelled the classname in the manifest file. the classname is MyFirstClass not 'MyFirstCLass'. Oh, so embarrassed

Answer (score 2):

> java /home/lighting/Documents/temp.jar Error: Could not find or load main class .home.lighting.Documents.temp.jar lightning

This shows that you clearly have done a mistake in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

See this [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for more informations.

Comment: 'clearly' never sounded better. will have a look :D

Comment: when I create the manifest file where do I put it?

Comment: see the `-m` option for the `jar` command

Comment: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
lightning@rigel5:~$ java -cp temp.jar MyFirstClass.lightning.java.hello
Error: Could not find or load main class MyFirstClass.lightning.java.hello
lightning@rigel5:~$

Comment: this is my MANIFEST.MN file;Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: lightning.java.hello.MyFirstClass
I created a file Manifest.txt and it looks like this;MainClass: lightning.java.hello.MyFirstCLass

Answer (score 2):

First you need a main-method in your class file - public static void main(String args[]){ ... } - probably done...

In the jar-file you need a manifest.txt file - inside the class with the main method has to be noted like this -> Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass

To create one you can use the commandline tool jar ...

If you don't have an manifest-file in your jar, you can just type:

```
java -cp jarFileName.jar ClassNameWithMainMethod
```

Comment: lightning@rigel5:~$ java -cp temp.jar.lightning.java.hello.MyFirstClass   I typed this in and got a java command usage index and did not display the file

Comment: @lightning you have a dot between the jar name and the classname in your command. Could this be the reason for it to be failing?

Comment: lightning@rigel5:~$ java -jar MyFirstClass.jar 
Error: Unable to access jarfile MyFirstClass.jar
lightning@rigel5:~$ temp.jar lightning.java.hello.MyFirstClass
temp.jar: command not found