# Shell script running but not opening terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, java

I'm having a problem executing a shell script in ubuntu, the script is set as executable and I enabled the execute instead of view option in Nautilus and the script does what it's meant to do which is launch a java jar, but it doesn't open the terminal and the app requires interaction from the terminal to function. How do I make it so that it runs the script from within terminal?

Also, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar example.jar
```

Comment: Instead of using the script, try running directly from a terminal `java -jar example.jar` and see what happens. If the same output is received, this might mean that's just the way the app run. Also consider checking this answer [How do I run a .JAR file via the terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/265245/how-do-i-run-a-jar-file-via-the-terminal)

Comment: No it works, doing ./run.sh (and java -jar example.jar) makes everything run as expected, its just that double clicking the script starts the process but not in terminal, I know this because I have to kill the process in task manager to run more than one instance of the process.

Comment: Is there a way to add gnome-terminal before java to indicate where java should run?

Comment: I don't know thats what I'm trying to find out xD

Comment: I'll look into this for you tomorrow and I'll post back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your `java` command in a `gnome-terminal` this way:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "java -version; bash"
```

Or to take your example:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "java -jar example.jar; bash"
```

You could even specify where to run your command:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=WORKING_DIR -x bash -c "java -jar example.jar; bash"
```

Running a `bash` command after the `java` one allow gnome-terminal to stay open even after the command is completed.